# Import certificates into the System Keychain via the command line

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, keychain

Is it possible to copy a certificate to a machine running OS X Snow Leopard, add it to the System Keychain, then set it to "Always Trust via SSH?"

And if so... how?

Comment: How to delete the cert once it is added: [How to delete Self-Signed certificate from System Keychain (Big Sur)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437772/how-to-delete-self-signed-certificate-from-system-keychain-big-sur)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To import a trusted certificate use the terminal command

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert \
  -d \
  -r trustRoot \
  -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
  <certificate>
```

This will add a trusted certificate to the `System.keychain`. You should modify the options and paths to suit your situation. See the [man page for *security*](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/security/) for more information.

↬ Rich Trouton, [*Adding new trusted root certificates to System.keychain*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202034859/https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/adding-new-trusted-root-certificates-to-system-keychain/)

Comment: The quotes messed me up for some reason, removed them and all was well.

Comment: @jaberg, and how to add certificate via ssh to local keychain, not system?

Comment: Thanks muchly! Just a note: One can also add to `"$HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"`

Comment: What is the difference between `security add-trusted-cert` and `security import`?

Comment: link is broken, : https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/security/

Comment: fyi to add a trusted CA to only the current user's Login keychain you don't need to sudo but you will be asked for your password: 

security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k  ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /tmp/my-root-ca.cer

Comment: Does this really work from a pure terminal? security want's to do some interactions despite the sudo.

Comment: @Martin, it was the same for me, I still got a GUI prompt for entering administrator password. Command from this answer does execute without such prompt (*and also certificate is trusted right away*): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223869/92892

Comment: it says error reading file

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer does not really work on newer versions of MacOS.
The correct command now is:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustAsRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate>
```

Note: tested with `MacOS 12(Monterey)` and `MacOS 13(Ventura)`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your answer could be improved by referencing which versions of macOS onward this change applies to. As it stands 'newer versions' doesn't provide a reference point, especially as the OP was asking about Snow Leopard. That was a long time ago (2009).

Comment: updated with a note as requested

Comment: What format did you have to use? For pem format, your command yielded `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.`