# How to delete Self-Signed certificate from System Keychain (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate

I just can't find a way to delete the Self-Signed Root CA from Keychain under System.

When I open KeyChain I select System under System Keychains. Then I click on the File in menu and then click on **Unlock Keychain "System"...**

After this I was expecting to be able to delete a certificate. But when I select a certificate I can only see greyed out Delete option in the Edit in the menu.

I tried to disable SIP (which was successful) but it did not help me clear From Keychain file (SystemRootKeychain) which is:

/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootKeychain.keychain

I disabled SIP in Recovery mode with command:
`csrutil disable`

Any advice?

Comment: What "self-signed certificate"?  What would SIP have to do with it?

Comment: I checked additional details and it's Root Internal Certificate which was needed for specific Wi-Fi Enterprise network connection. Now the connection to the Wi-Fi network is possible without this certificate so I want to delete it.
I found info about SIP here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357200

Comment: I’m going to edit the post and answer so the clarified problem is all in the question and the solution is about where to look for others. Great resolution  !

Answer (score 1):

I was able to delete it with terminal command:

```
sudo security delete-certificate -c "CERT_NAME" /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

It was not clear to look in /Library/Keychains instead of  /System/Library/Keychains so SIP was an unrelated complication to get to the source of the item.

Comment: Added a self-signed certificate via `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain CERT_NAME` (per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/80625/263317)), but when I try to delete it with the above command, I get `Unable to delete certificate matching "CERT_NAME"`. However, when I do it manually in Keychain Access, it works (after needing to put in my password twice), but I was hoping for a solution that works on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
# 1.
sudo security remove-trusted-cert -d <CERT_FILE_NAME>

# 2.
sudo security delete-certificate -c <CERT_COMMON_NAME> /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

---

On **Ventura**, I added a self-signed certificate to the System keychain using the [Import certificates into the System Keychain via the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80623/import-certificates-into-the-system-keychain-via-the-command-line) thread:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert \
  -d \
  -r trustRoot \
  -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
  <CERT_FILE_NAME>
```

In [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac), under "*System*",

[image: Sidebar in Keychain Access],

the added certificate will show up like this:

[image: the certificate in Keychain Access, marked with a white plus sign in a blue dot]

---

#### Deleting a certificate from the System keychain on the terminal

##### Step 0. Make sure that [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) is **not** running.

If you see the little white dot beneath its icon, then quit.

[image: the white dot under Keychain Access icon]

If you forget, the steps below will work to some extent, but the certificate will have to be manually deleted as well, defeating the whole purpose of doing this in the terminal. You will still get an error,

[image: "An error occurred while deleting the certificate"]

In my case, quitting and starting [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) again didn't help, hence this manual step.

##### Step 1. `sudo security remove-trusted-cert -d <CERT_FILE_NAME>`

For example,

```
% sudo security remove-trusted-cert -d localhost.crt
```

This is how the certificate looks like in [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) at this point:

[image: The same certificate icon but now without the white cross on blue dot.]

##### Step 2. `sudo security delete-certificate -c <CERT_COMMON_NAME> /Library/Keychains/System.keychain`

The argument for `-c` has to be the **common name** on the certificate (i.e., the `CN` parameter). This is what shows up in [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac).

In my case, it is `lynx_localhost_test`. To check it on the terminal, decode the certificate with `openssl`:

```
% openssl x509 -in localhost.crt -text | grep 'Subject:'

        Subject: C=US, ST=Denial, L=Springfield, O=Dis, CN=lynx_localhost_test
```

To check this on the terminal without opening up [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac), before deleting the cert:

```
% sudo security find-certificate -c lynx_localhost_test
```