# How to export certificates (.crt) from System Keychain via command line?

Tags: macos, mac, keychain, ventura

My question is identical to [Import certificates into the System Keychain via the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80623/import-certificates-into-the-system-keychain-via-the-command-line) except I need a way to get an existing certificate in the form of a crt file via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for certificates in pem format (which is the same thing as what's in the crt file) using the `security` module:

```
% security find-certificate -c RCA -p
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In this example I'm searching for a certificate that matches the pattern "RCA".

Once you have this stdout you can use it as you wish.